# Is there an equivalent to pd.DataFrame.at[index, column] for a MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I need to set a value of a cell in a pandas DataFrame that has a MultiIndex. Is there a way similar to pd.DataFrame.at[index, column] that I can use on a MultiIndex DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
arrays = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=arrays, names=["i", "k"])
partial_corr = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_index, columns=arrays[0])


partial_corr
Out[5]: 
       a    b    c
i k               
a a  NaN  NaN  NaN
  b  NaN  NaN  NaN
  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
b a  NaN  NaN  NaN
  b  NaN  NaN  NaN
  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
c a  NaN  NaN  NaN
  b  NaN  NaN  NaN
  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

In the DataFrame partial_corr, I'd like to be able to get/set the value of

```
partial_corr.at["a", "b", "b"]
```

where the first entry in .at[] is for index "i", the second entry is for index "k", and the third entry is for the column...similar to the way a single index DataFrame can return the value of df.at["a", "b"] where the first entry is the index and the second entry is the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexSlice` is for multiple index

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
partial_corr.loc[idx['a', 'b'], idx['b']]
Out[431]: nan
```